# ending the life of a thread in python?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have the below code but it lives on after the queue is empty, any insights:

```
def processor():
   while(1>0):
    if queue.empty() == True:  
    print "the Queue is empty!"  
    break
   source=queue.get()
   page = urllib2.urlopen(source)
   print page   

def main:
   for i in range(threads):  
    th = Thread(target=processor)  
    th.setDaemon(True)  
    th.start()  
   queue.join()
```

It prints queue empty as many times as I have threads and just stands there doing nothing.

Comment: Please fix the indentation and post a complete example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call queue.task_done() after printing the page, otherwise join() will block. Each thread, after using get() must call task_done().

See [documentation for queue](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html)

Comment: If your threads die when there is no work left in the queue, you can join to the threads (instead of the queue) without needing to call task_done().

Answer (score 3):

This part:

```
   while(1>0):
    if queue.empty() == True:  
    print "the Queue is empty!"  
    break
```

Above is just plain **wrong**. `queue.get()` is blocking, there is absolutely no reason to have a [busy loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_loop). It should be deleted.

Your code should look something like this.

```
def processor():
   source=queue.get()
   page = urllib2.urlopen(source)
   print page   
   queue.task_done()

def main:
   for i in range(threads):  
    th = Thread(target=processor)  
    th.setDaemon(True)  
    th.start()  
   for source in all_sources:
    queue.put(source)
   queue.join()
```

It's not the cleanest way to exit, but it will work. Since processor threads are set to be daemons, whole process with exit as soon as the `main` is done.

Answer (score 1):

As Max said, need a complete example to help with your behavior, but from the documentation:

> Python’s Thread class supports a subset of the behavior of Java’s Thread class; currently, there are no priorities, no thread groups, and threads cannot be destroyed, stopped, suspended, resumed, or interrupted.
>
> It stops being alive when its run() method terminates – either normally, or by raising an unhandled exception. The is_alive() method tests whether the thread is alive.

http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html

The lower level thread module does allow you to manually call exit().  Without a more complete example, I don't know if that's what you need in this case, but I suspect not as Thread objects should automatically end when run() is complete.

http://docs.python.org/library/thread.html

Comment: And the recommendation with Python is to use multiprocessing rather than multithreading, is it not (for non-I/O intensive tasks, at least)? As multiple threads won't actually run concurrently even if you have them executing on different processors due to the global interpreter lock. I guess that doesn't matter for Max as he will have plenty of I/O waits.